# Is there a way to set the JwtIssuer id_token_lifetime_secs from the url

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I have a custom policy with the following JwtIssuer TechnicalProfile

```
<TechnicalProfile Id="JwtIssuer">
  <DisplayName>JWT Issuer</DisplayName>
  <Protocol Name="None" />
  <OutputTokenFormat>JWT</OutputTokenFormat>
  <Metadata>
    <Item Key="client_id">{service:te}</Item>
    <Item Key="issuer_refresh_token_user_identity_claim_type">objectId</Item>
    <Item Key="SendTokenResponseBodyWithJsonNumbers">true</Item>
    <Item Key="AuthenticationContextReferenceClaimPattern">None</Item>
    <Item Key="id_token_lifetime_secs">600</Item>
    <Item Key="token_lifetime_secs">600</Item>
  </Metadata>
  <CryptographicKeys>
    <Key Id="issuer_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_TokenSigningKeyContainer" />
    <Key Id="issuer_refresh_token_key" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_TokenEncryptionKeyContainer" />
  </CryptographicKeys>
  <InputClaims />
  <OutputClaims />
</TechnicalProfile>
```

I would like to set the the lifetime keys to a value passed as a url param So I tried

```
<Item Key="id_token_lifetime_secs">{OAUTH-KV:tokenexpiry}</Item>
<Item Key="token_lifetime_secs">{OAUTH-KV:tokenexpiry}</Item>
```

But when I loaded the policy I get an error

Validation failed: 1 validation error(s) found in policy "B2C_1A_XXXX_MFA_SIGNIN_TRUSTFRAMEWORKBASE" of tenant "xxx.onmicrosoft.com".Input string was not in a correct format.

Is this the correct way to do this, or is a different way I can set the lifetime based on the auth url?

Comment: Actually this may not be a not idea as would allow clients to create tokens with very long expiry :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe that this is supported because it isn't recommended as a good practice. :)